# How do I make this model query work?

Tags: django

I'm trying to find a solution that will return the objects with a specific id.

I have these models:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    customid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    <-- data -->
class ModelA(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB, blank=True, null=True, related_name="Bs")
```

and I have this code in my views:

```
a = ModelA.objects.filter(ModelB__customid = Bobject_id)
```

I want to be able to find all of the A objects with a given B object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Surely `a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,...)` should be `b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB,...)`

Comment: fixed it in my example! still need help

Answer (score 0):

```
a_objects = ModelA.objects.filter(b__customid=Bobject_id)
```

Check out the documentation for [creating queries that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an instance of ModelB, the easiest way is to follow the reverse relationship from there:

```
a_objects = b_object.Bs.all()
```

This uses the explicit related_name you have set: without that, it would have been `b_object.modela_set.all()`. Note that your related_name should really be "As", not "Bs", since it refers to the A objects that are related to that B.